# positioning the watermark php GD

Tags: php, gd

I want the watermark to go BELOW the image, so the overall height of image should expand.

Here is my code:

```
$img_width=imagesx($img);
$img_height=imagesy($img);
$watermark=imagecreatefrompng($watermark);  
$watermark_width=imagesx($watermark);  
$watermark_height=imagesy($watermark);  
$image=imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);  
imagealphablending($image, false);
$dest_x=$img_width-$watermark_width-5;
$dest_y=$img_height-$watermark_height+1;
imagecopy($img, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

I tried playing with watermark_width and height no luck.
Is this even possible?

Comment: This is GD, not imagemagick - so you want the output to be in `(image-width)x(image-height+watermark-height)` dimensions?

Comment: height of watermark is 30px .. images can be of different dimensions

Comment: I just ask, you want the watermark below the original image *physically*, or you want to be below as a *layer*?

Comment: physically.. i hide the watermark with css.. so it only shows up when the image is embedded or opened in new tab/downloaded etc

Comment: You know, watermarks below images are useless at all. A screenshot, a simple crop and you remove it as easy as it is to download it. A watermark at the bottom of your image with a 90% transparency shouldn't be better?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create an image with dimensions:

   `imagecreatetruecolor(max($img_width,$watermark_width), $img_height + $watermark_height + $margin);`
2. then, copy the image to `(0,0)`
3. last, copy the watermark to `(0,$img_height + $margin)`

(`$margin` is the space between image & watermark in pixels)

**Edit**:

```
$margin    = 5;
$img       = imagecreatefrompng($img_path);
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_path);

$img_width  = imagesx($img);
$img_height = imagesy($img);

$watermark_width  = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

$output_width  = max($img_width, $watermark_width);
$output_height = $img_height + $watermark_height + $margin;

$output = imagecreatetruecolor($output_width, $output_height);
imagesavealpha($output, true);
imagealphablending($output, false);
imagerectangle($output, 0, 0, $output_width, $output_height, imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127));

imagecopy($output, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height);
imagecopy($output, $watermark, 0, $img_height + $margin, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);

imagepng($output, $path_to_save); // use null to output
imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($output);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt seem to work..i am probably doing something wrong..this sounds too noobish..but can you post the code..pretty please